# C++14 static constexpr member array fails at linking

Tags: c++, linker, c++14, constexpr

I'm having some difficulties with `static constexpr` attributes: it works with integral types, with `enum class` members, but when I try to do it with a statically initialized integral array it fails at linking saying `undefined reference to S::a` inside `main`.

That is with either clang 3.9 or g++ 6.3, and ld 2.27.90; and all that with `-std=c++14`.

Here is the quickest snippet to reproduce this:

```
struct S
{
  static constexpr int a[5] = {0};
};


int main()
{
  S s{};
  [[gnu::unused]] int b = s.a[0]; // force S stuff to be emitted
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any suggestion you may have for this situation.

Comment: You need to define your object; at namespace scope: `constexpr int S::a[5];`

Comment: @ildjarn thanks ! but do you know why I do have to do this for arrays but not for other stuff like plain integral types ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
enum class E { foo, bar };
struct S
{
  static constexpr int a[5] = {0};
  static constexpr int b = 42;
  static constexpr E e = foo;
};
```

All of above are *declarations*, and are *not* definitions. For each one, you must provide a *definition*:

```
int S::a[5];
int S::b;
E S::e;
```

> it works with integral types, with enum class members

This works more or less *by accident*. Specifically, it works because you never have a context where the address of that variable is taken (never ODR-use the variable).

Often I see people adding an innocent-looking call to `std::max`, and suddenly discovering that they didn't provide a definition. That is:

```
int main()
{
   printf("%d\n", S::b);       // works fine
   int x = std::max(1, S::b);  // fails to link in non-optimized build.
}
```